# Dit Names and Gender

Tags: genre, noms-propres

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dit_name), there's a feminine form of the French-Canadian "dit" name spelled "dite", as in, *Josephine Roy dite Lauzon*.

That was the only specific name I could find after looking at hundreds of parish records.  Part of the difficulty for me is that the "dite" name was often omitted from the narrative of the record, as in, "...baptisé Henriette née le même jour du légitime mariage de François...", where only the father's dit name was written.

Can I safely assume the gender agrees with the individual, rather than the family name?  Or, would a Joseph Chapelle use the feminine form?

What level of importance would be placed upon the correct gender in a dit name?  Is agreement needed for formality?  Was this simply never standardized?

Edited, for those unfamiliar with these *dit* names:

The surname *Roy dit Lauzon* would be inherited from the father.  It was generally used by the whole family for 2 or 3 generations before the old surname was dropped.

Comment: I just don't get how a Family name could have a gender... As the Wikipedia page you link to *dit/dite* means "called", it is the person who is called of course. Note that this custom can be found in France, although not as frequently as in French-speaking Canada. Se [here](https://www.lanouvellerepublique.fr/a-la-une/les-regles-pour-pseudonymes) for example.

Comment: @None Ici, n'est-ce pas _Josephine_ qui induit l'accord de _dit(e)_ au féminin? Je ne sais pas si _Josephine_ a un genre en tant que nom, mais la personne qui porte ce nom est sans doute une femme, ce qui rend _dite_ tout à fait approprié?

Comment: @Frank C'est ce que je dis, non ?  La personne qui s'appelle Josephine est habituellement une femme. Un homme ne s'appellerait pas Josephine en principe (mais imaginable, bien sûr, auquel cas on utiliserait *dit*)

Comment: @None OK, c'était pas clair pour moi, mais on est d'accord. J'ai upvoté ta réponse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dit* is an adjective. In French adjectives always agree with the noun they qualify. As indicated on the Wikipedia page you link to *dit/dite* means "called", it is the person who is "called" something or other, i.e. given an alias. So for a woman we'd have : *Josephine Roy dite Lauzon* and for a man *Joseph Roy dit Lauzon*.

In case of a gender-neutral given name we'd have, for example, *Dominique Leroux dit Peluche* in the case of Dominique being a man, and *Dominique Leroux dite Peluche* in the case of Dominique being a woman.

If necessary the alias can be masculine or feminine as appropriate. For example we could have *Paul Legendre dit Parisien* or *Paule Legendre dite Parisienne*.

This custom of giving aliases is found in France as well, although probably not as often as in French-speaking Canada. You can read about it [on that page](https://www.lanouvellerepublique.fr/a-la-une/les-regles-pour-pseudonymes).

**Edit** after reading the [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54056/dit-names-and-gender#comment115226_54057):

If I saw *Joséphine Roy dit Lauzon*, to me it would undoubtedly mean that *Lauzon* applies to *Roy* and is part of the family name. But this isn't the case described in your question, and I do not think anyone would write *dit* without gender if the dit name concerned the person whose first name is mentioned.

But, indeed when looking at records, it can sometimes be hard to distinguish between the family name and the dit name as in the long run the dit name can become part of the family name. Here's an extract of the page  [Les "noms dits"](https://www.francogene.com/quebec/nomsdits.php) from the website [Francogene](https://www.francogene.com/):

> Après quelques générations, il n'est plus évident de décider ce qui est le patronyme ou le surnom et nous pourrions trouver par exemple: Beauregard dit Jarret. De plus, il est aussi possible que les patronyme et surnom aient été inversé dès le premier usage du "nom dit".*

---

<sub>* [sic]</sub>

Comment: Thank you.  And for even more clarity, when I see a parish record for the same person under "Joséphine Roy dit Lauzon" is that to be considered a mistake, or a style variation, or someone who just always writes "dit" without gender?

Comment: @RobertChapin In that case, maybe the _dit_ refers to Roy (family name), rather than Joséphine though?

Comment: @RobertChapin I don't think that would contradict None's answer. She explained why *dite* was used in some of the records you found but that doesn't rule out the fact someone else could have considered her name to be the invariable compound "Roy dit Lauzon".

Comment: My guess is that if the nickname was specific to the person agreement was mandatory, if the nickname was actually an alternate first name, agreement was definitely mandatory but if the nickname was shared with one of their parents, agreement was optional. Here the nickname is likely the name of a town and was possibly inherited from her father. Elsewhere, agreement (*dit*, *dite* and *dits*) was mandatory, e.g. *la dite Joséphine Roy dit(e) Lauzon*.

Comment: Maybe we are not really solving the question, meaning that in the case "Joséphine Roy dite Lauzon", it's not clear to me now, what "Lauzon" refers to: 1. _Joséphine_ alone? 2. _Joséphine Roy_? or 3. Just _Roy_? One way to decide could be to see if "Lauzon" is used elsewhere to denote a place, or another family name, or was used as a nickname to replace a first name.

Comment: @Frank  Just to fill in what jlliagre said. These type of aliases mots often refer to place or occupation.  Lauzon is a place name (a river in the south east of France and a place in Québec) and a job. Lauzon was the surname given to those who worked *lauze*, a kind of flagstone used for roofing. Apparently Lauzons form the south east of France immigrated  to North America where we find the name nowadays. A Jean de Lauzon immigrated to Québec and founded the town of Lauzon (now part of Lévis).

Comment: I can see some confusion. Regardless of the grammar, these *dit* names in parish records were part of the family name, the surname, and inherited by children.  The two names were interchangeable, and after 2 or 3 generations they would stop using the old name.  So the "alias" was not unique to one person, but in the records was used (sometimes) as part of an individual's full name.

Comment: I added 2 more sentences to the question to help.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a problem anymore then :-) Whether it's _Roy dit Lauzon_ or _Roy dite Lauzon_, the Roy family at some point was dealing with _lauzes_ (I know those very well, many in Ardèche), and that's that. If the Roy family member is a woman, you can use _dite_. If you don't, there is no ambiguity though.

Comment: I just found a public genealogy of a *Roy dit Lauzon* family where the older known member was *[Antoine Roy](https://gw.geneanet.org/fhammond?lang=fr&iz=2&p=antoine&n=roy)* born in1635 in France. One of his grand-son was named Augustin-Louis Roy dit Desjardins dit Lauzier (born in 1701) and had himself a grand-son who was the first of the name: *[Pierre-Antoine-Martin Roy dit Lauzon](https://gw.geneanet.org/fhammond?lang=fr&iz=2&p=pierre+antoine+martin&n=roy+dit+lauzon)* (born in 1762, Sainte-Anne-de-la-Pocatière, Kamouraska). Both Lauzier and Lauzon indeed refer to the *lauze*.

Comment: One thing that's certain, these people never ever imagined we would talk about them on the internet in this forum :-)

Comment: @Frank Don't underestimate the KIngs known as Flagstoners.

Comment: @RobertChapin Are you able to trace what happens to that family up to today? Are they still carrying the same name? What happened to _Lauzon_ in their name?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extra part of the answer.  I'm adding to the excellent information already posted.

I believe there is a regional component to the expression of gender in *dit* names.  I found a 2nd example of the feminine *dite* in my research and started scrolling through microfilm images within the same parish.  In the parish of Saint-Germain-de-Rimouski during the mid 1840s, use of *dit* names was rare overall, but the priests consistently wrote *dit* for men and *dite* for women.

Most of my research has focused on parishes and/or eras where the feminine *dite* was never written.  They would write only one surname in the margin without the *dit* name and then mention the father's *dit* name in the narrative.  There are also examples where *dit* was used without gender agreement.

As pointed out in the comments, there is no ambiguity in either spelling, just some inconsistency.